# Nextjs - Error building Type error: Object is of type 'unknown'

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm making an application with prismic, getting the posts generated, but in GetServerSideProps, I'm having a Type error: Object is of type 'unknown' error. I've already tried typing and it's not working or I'm not doing it right, can someone help me solve this problema

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import Head from "next/head";
import { RichText } from "prismic-dom";
import { getPrismicClient } from "../../services/prismic";
import styles from "./post.module.scss";
import { ParsedUrlQuery } from "querystring";

interface IParams extends ParsedUrlQuery {
  slug: string;
}
interface PostProps {
  post: {
    slug: String;
    title: String;
    content: string;
    updatedAt: String;
  };
}

export default function Post({ post }: PostProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{post.title} | Ignews</title>
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.container}>
        <article className={styles.post}>
          <h1>{post.title}</h1>
          <time>{post.updatedAt}</time>
          <div
            className={styles.postContent}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }}
          />
        </article>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<PostProps> = async (
  context
) => {
  const { slug } = context.params as IParams;
  const prismic = getPrismicClient();

  const response = await prismic.getByUID("publications", String(slug), {});
  const post = {
    slug,
    title: RichText.asText(response.data.title), //Type error: Object is of type 'unknown'.
    content: RichText.asHtml(response.data.content), //Type error: Object is of type 'unknown'.
    updatedAt: new Date(response.last_publication_date).toLocaleDateString(
      "pt-BR",
      {
        day: "2-digit",
        month: "long",
        year: "numeric",
      }
    ), //Type error: Object is of type 'unknown'.
  };
  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you show us how have you tried to type it? Can you also share the code for the `getPrismicClient` function?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this:

```
  const response = await prismic.getByUID("publications", String(slug), {});
```

returns an error. execute it in `try/catch`

```
  try{
     const response = await prismic.getByUID("publications", String(slug), {});
}
   catch(e){
     console.log("error in fetching", e.message)
}
```

A better way would be

```
updatedAt: new Date(response?.last_publication_date).toLocaleDateString
```

Comment: I tried but the error persists, if I use the try inside getServerSideProps the error in it, I tried to put response?. but even so it gives an error to the build, in development it works normally but in production it gives this error, of types, Type error: Object is of type 'unknown'.

Comment: Do u get response? Console. Log it

Comment: yes, in development it comes normal everything works ok, even if I go to the nextjs settings and put it to ignore ts in the build, it works normally the problem is that without it it keeps giving this error as if it had not been typed